# Is it possible to dynamically filter a JSON object so only fields matching the filter text are displayed using Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I apologize if this has been asked before; I couldn't find the answer.

Here is my problem:

I am consuming a complex JSON object from a web service in my Angular app. I am then displaying that JSON object in tree form to the user (using ngx json viewer).

Since the tree is large and complex, I wanted to offer users the ability to narrow down which fields they see in the view.

I have not been able to figure out how to filter the fields from the JSON that display based on the filter text I am receiving from the input box. I know I can query and filter for certain field values, but I have not seen how to filter on the names of the fields themselves.

So if I have this JSON:

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "phone": "999-999-9999",
    "address": "123 Main St"
}
```

And the user enters the filter text "name", I want to display just the matching fields:

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith"
}
```

Does this make sense? Is it possible to do?

Thanks all!

Comment: Object.keys(o).filter(o=>o.includes("name"))

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(o).filter(o=>o.includes("name"))
```

This will give you the matching keys but not the values for those keys.

```
var o = {
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "phone": "999-999-9999",
    "address": "123 Main St"};

var matchingKeys = Object.keys(o).filter(o=>o.includes("name"));
var filteredObject = {};

matchingKeys.forEach(key => filteredObject[key] = o[key]);
```

This will make the filteredObject become:

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith"
}
```

And as a typescript function...

```
public filterObjectContainsKey(a_sFilterKey: string, a_oObject: Object): Object {

    var matchingKeys = Object.keys(a_oObject).filter(o=>o.includes(a_sFilterKey));
    var filteredObject = {};

    matchingKeys.forEach(key => filteredObject[key] = a_oObject[key]);
    return filteredObject;
}
```